# iTunes first release with good/bas version number

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, xcode7, app-store-connect

Does the first release has to be 1.0 or 1.0.0 ?

I Made my first release to App Store version 1.0.1 ... 
In Xcode and in the .plist I set 1.0.1 and in iTunes Connect 1.0.1 too.
**Does this build Will be rejected for that ? Thank you**

Comment: It won't be rejected for version number

Comment: Have you experienced this ? I'm really worried about loosing time with this validation. Thank you

Comment: Your app won't be rejected, I have personally experienced it. Apps are rejected on version number ONLY when its less than 1, indicating it is not ready yet.

Comment: @sasquatch Thank you very much for your help.